# Rotation support in custom transitions - Constraints or update frame on rotation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I am creating a 'semi-modal' transition that displays content from the bottom of the screen but does not fill the whole screen.

The height of the modal is dependent on the preferred content size of the toViewController (if the preferred size is larger than the container view then it will be capped at a certain height).

This is all working expected until it comes to rotation.

The current transition works using frames so we the device is rotated with a semiModal view displayed it is positioned incorrectly (see screenshots).

[image: SemiModal transition presented in Portrait]
[image: Transition after rotation]

It seems that by default the containerView (part of the transitionContext) has W+H auto resizing mask. The toViewController also has W+H.

What I really want for this transition is for the height to be fixed, width to be flexible and for it to be ‘pinned’ to the bottom of the container view.

This can be achieved by using constrains in the transition e.g

```
// in animateTransition:
UIView *toView = toViewController.view;
toView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; // Should a transition really be altering this?
[containerView addSubview:toView];

[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[toView]-0-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(toView)]];

[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[toView(height)]-0-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:@{@"height" : @(endFrame.size.height)} views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(toView)]];
```

But the question is are we allowed to add constraints to the containerView? From all the examples I have seen only frames have been used in the transition.

Alternatively, I can update the frame during rotation by asking the transition for it’s preferred size for the given rotation. However, this seems fairly messy and means I have to keep a reference to the transition, the transition would have to keep a reference to the container view and toView (although this could be weak) and the viewController needs to ask for the new frame during rotation.

```
// In the VC that presents the semiModal view
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    if (self.presentedViewController && _tansitionDelegate) { // if showing a VC that was presented using a custom transition
        [self updateViewControllerPresentedWithTransitionsFrame];
    }
}

- (void)updateViewControllerPresentedWithTransitionsFrame {
    CGRect endFrame = [_tansitionDelegate endFrame]; // transition delegate asks the transition for the new frame for the current orientation. This is calculated based on the frame of the transitions containerView and the toViewControllers preferred size
    self.presentedViewController.view.frame = endFrame;
}
```

Both of these approaches seem to work but it would be nice to know the recommended way to do this? Or if I am missing any specific transition rotation API :)

**Update**

I tried to expand on the constraint approach to make sure that the presented view could not be more than 0.75 of the height of it's parent (this was previously done using frame calculation).

```
[containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:toView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                             toItem:containerView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         multiplier:kDefaultModalProportion
                                                           constant:0]];
```

Unfortunately this causes an unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints error as the containerView is using autoResizingMasks. So it looks like this can only be correctly implemented with frames which are updated by a view controller during rotation?

Comment: I think the whole point of constraints is to update parts of the UI when other parts change, including rotation, so I would imagine the constraints option is fine.

Comment: Yeah the whole app is written with constraints it just seems odd that non of the custom transition examples or WWDC videos seem to be using constraints in UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning